# Why is this erroring out? Can you only have one EXCEPTION in this entire stored procedure / block of code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Pardon my ignorance but, let's say you have a stored procedure that is performing two simple merges. Do you need an exception / raise for each merge? Or just one exception at the end? Below is an example of what I am talking about:

```
MERGE INTO table@oradb T
USING
    (SELECT FROM_TX,
        TO_TX,
        LOCAL_TIME_TS
FROM    V_DATA
WHERE data_date_dt is not null) S ON (
            T.FROM = S.FROM_TX
               AND T.TO = S.TO_TX
               AND T.TIMESTAMP_ = S.UTC_HR_TS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET T.VAL                = S.value_nb,
            T.BA_LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = S.LOCAL_TIME_ts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT 
        (FROM, TO, DATE_,)
        VALUES   
        (S.FROM_BA, S.TO_BA, S.data_date_dt);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN NULL;
RAISE;
MERGE INTO table@oradb B
USING
    (SELECT FROM_TX,
        TO_TX,
        LOCAL_TIME_TS
FROM    V_DATA_2
WHERE data_date_dt is not null) S ON (
            B.FROM = S.FROM_TX
               AND B.TO = S.TO_TX
               AND B.TIMESTAMP_ = S.UTC_HR_TS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET B.VAL                = S.value_nb,
            B.BA_LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = S.LOCAL_TIME_ts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT 
        (FROM, TO, DATE_,)
        VALUES   
        (B.FROM_BA, B.TO_BA, B.data_date_dt);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN NULL;
RAISE;
```

Any suggestions (also) on what I can be doing better? If it helps, FROM_TX, TO_TX and LOCAL_TIME_TS make up the composite primary key in table@oradb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?  You can have multiple exception handlers.  FYI, having a "WHEN OTHERS NULL" exception handler is just about the worst thing you can do for error handling.  You are hiding the error details.

Comment: Well, it has a `RAISE` too, which makes catching it all pointless really. And the second `MERGE` is within the first exception handler, but anything after the `RAISE` is never going to be reached. It doesn't look like you need or want multiple exception handlers but it's hard to tell.

Comment: The error is a Primary Key violation. I've tried using WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX but it doesn't work (for some odd reason) . I'm probably doing something wrong. Question @OldProgrammer, if i am creating this exception and the proc lands on an entry that violates a constraint (for example a PK) will it continue to load the rest of the data? if not do you know how I may be able to do this?

Comment: DML statements are all-or-nothing (unless you use [DML error logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2)). An exception will abort the entire procedure.

Comment: DOH. is there a way I can have it continue even if one entry fails in the middle?

Comment: Sure, handle the exception.

Comment: Will it continue with the rest of the entries then if i do that? Do you know what the error message for that would be? would the proper code to add be: WHEN  OTHERS THEN NULL ?

Comment: No it will not continue.  You should not be getting a WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception in a MERGE statement, as its whole purpose is to do an insert only if you do not get a match.  So there is something wrong in your merge statement regarding match criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write like this

```
Create or replace Procedure proc1(param...)
is
Begin
     Begin
        Merge statement...
     Exception
         When others then
            Null
     End;
     2nd Merge statement...
Exception
  When other then
     raise_application_error(...);
End;
```